# laravel get value from array of controllers

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

this is my `PermissionController.php`

```
foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route)
{
    $action = $route->getAction();

    if (array_key_exists('controller', $action))
    {
       $controllers[] = $action['controller'];
    }
}
return view('permission.create')->withControllers($controllers);
```

and my `permission/create/php` is like this :

```
{!! Form::select('class_name[]', $controllers, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple']) !!}
```

here in controller, it put the name of all controllers in `$controller` and send it to the `blade` but when i select some of them, the request gives me their keys instead of value

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->get('class_name');
}
```

if I select the first one and third one the output is for example :`{"1","3"}`
but I want their value like this : `{"UserController.php", "TestController.php"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code instead Forms::Select or create your custom List with Laravel built-in List Function :

```
<select name="class_name[]" multiple>
@foreach($controllers as $class)
    <option value="{{$class}}" >{{$class}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

or simply replace the

```
 $controllers[] = $action['controller'];
```

with

```
$controllers[$action['controller']] = $action['controller'];
```